# How to get bandwidth quota usage with Google app engine api?

Tags: java, python, api, google-app-engine

I want to know if Google App Engine support using `google.appengine.api.quota` package to get bandwidth usage, not cpu usage?

If so, how to get with Python or Java and print in webpage?

Comment: This is not currently available; you might want to star http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can get a very close estimate of this by adding up the length of the request headers and body for incoming requests, and the response body and headers for responses.

Answer (score -1):

Reading [the javadoc](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/quota/QuotaService.html) gives the answer: no.

And no, I won't mail you this answer. You write here, you read here.